# How can I sort in descending order?

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, struct

I'm trying to sort for the top and second top value of `totalRevenue` and its `name`. I've tried to sort them in descending order this way but I could not figure it out how to make it work. Can anyone please help me out? 
First two entries:

```
1002 Hammer  23.65  203 
1024 Nails  6.95  400
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Structure to hold statistics
struct Selling {
    int productNumber;
    string name;
    double price;
    int soldNumber;
    double totalRevenue[];
};

int main()
{
    ifstream statFile;
    string productName;
    double price;
    int productNumber, soldNumber;
    Selling *productArray[100];
    Selling *aSelling;
    int numProduct = 0;
    int man = 0;

    statFile.open("sales.txt");

    while (numProduct < 100 && statFile >> productNumber >> productName >> price >> soldNumber)
    {
        Selling *aSelling = new Selling;
        aSelling->productNumber = productNumber;
        aSelling->name = productName;
        aSelling->price = price;
        aSelling->soldNumber = soldNumber;
        aSelling->totalRevenue[] = aSelling->price * aSelling->soldNumber;
        productArray[numProduct++] = aSelling;

        //cout << aSelling->productNumber<< " " << aSelling->name << " " << aSelling->price << " " << aSelling->soldNumber << " " << aSelling->totalRevenue << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (aSelling->totalRevenue[i] > aSelling->totalRevenue[j]) {
                man = aSelling->totalRevenue[i];
                aSelling->totalRevenue[i] = aSelling->totalRevenue[j];
                aSelling->totalRevenue[i] = man;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << "The top selling product is " << aSelling->name << "with total sales of " << aSelling->totalRevenue[i] << endl;
        cout << "The second top selling product is " << aSelling->name << "with total sales of " << aSelling->totalRevenue[i - 1] << endl;
    }
}
```

And there is an unexpected expression error at the line `aSelling->totalRevenue[] = aSelling->price * aSelling->soldNumber;` which I don't understand.

Comment: `aSelling->totalRevenue[???]` - you need to access an element within an array. `[]` on its own is meaningless. But what is `double totalRevenue[]` supposed to mean anyway? Do you just want a single value here, not an array? Then use `double totalRevenue`.

Comment: @Minh Nguyen why aren't you using std::vector?

Comment: Also, is this some sort of homework assignment where you are limited on which parts of the Standard Library you are allowed to use?

Comment: Use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: Why do you use dynamic memory allocation? It's not necessary here. Where do you clean up the allocated memory?

Comment: @BoBTFish it was aSelling->totalRevenue without []. By using this sorting method I think I have to add []. Is it supposed to be that way or should I just get rid of them? I'm recommeded to use bubble sort or selection sort.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'm required to use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: From the nested `for` loops further down, it seems like `totalRevenue` is supposed to be an array containing 5 values (why 5??). In which case, your declaration needs to be like `double totalRevenue[5];`, and you need to access it by providing an index for the position of the element you want to access within that.

Comment: If you have to use dynamic memory allocation you have to delete the allocated memory with `delete` resp. `delete[]`

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do with your program. `double totalRevenue[];` is pointer. You don't allocate memory for it. You can't assign a value to it.

Comment: @BoBTFish 5 because there are currently 5 products in the sales.txt file.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I was able to output all the double totalRevenue with the blocked line in the while loop, but I just want to output the top two highest value that's why I made it double totalRevenue[]; and tried to sort them with the for loop.

Comment: @MinhNguyen So there are 5 products, but each product would only have one value for its `totalRevenue`, correct? In which case, this should **not** be an array. You would then sort the whole list of products, based on their individual `totalRevenue` values.

Comment: Currently you a reading up to 100 `aSelling`s, each containing one `totalRevenue`. Then you try to sort 5 `totalRevenue`s of the last `aSelling`. That makes no sense

Comment: @BoBTFish So the whole for loop is not the right choice? How do I sort the whole list based on their totalRevenue values?

Comment: @MinhNguyen `double totalRevenue[];` is not the correct choice. It's not valid C++. How many values does that array contain do you think?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I actually have no idea.

Comment: @MinhNguyen You need to loop over the things you are trying to sort. In this case, that is the products. Loop over the products, and compare the `totalRevenue` value within each.

Comment: @MinhNguyen Ok. That declares a flexible array and it doesn't exist in C++. `std::vector<double> totalRevenue;` is what you've got at your disposal in C++ instead. Edit your question and add the first two `Selling` entries that you have in your file.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ok I added the first two entries.

Comment: @MinhNguyen Great! It does not look like you need a flexible amount of `double` for your `totalRevenue`. Why not simply make it `double totalRevenue;`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo It was double totalRevenue;. I made it with [] just because I thought that would work with the for loop below. Then I realized it would not. So now I just make it double totalRevenue; get rid of that for loop and find another sorting way which I'm still struggling. BoBTFish gave an idea and I'm still trying to find the right way for that.

Comment: @MinhNguyen Good. Does the file always contain exactly 100 products or could that be a variable amount?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's a variable amount. It's not always 100. Maximum amount is 100.

Comment: @MinhNguyen Ok, then using `std::vector<Selling> productArray;` to store what you read from the file would be good. There are plently of examples of how to read data from files, putting it in objects and then putting the objects into `std::vector`s here at SO if you search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion on the arrays to sort:

- you should define `totalRevenue` as a `double`, not an array of doubles,
- should be sort the first `numProduct` elements of the array `productArray` based on the criteria `totalRevenue` and `name`, the order is determined by the comparison operator used. Only compare the second criteria if the first criteria give equal values.

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Structure to hold statistics
struct Selling {
    int productNumber;
    string name;
    double price;
    int soldNumber;
    double totalRevenue;
};

int compareSellings(const Selling *a, const Selling *b) {
    // sort in decreasing order of totalRevenue
    if (a->totalRevenue > b->totalRevenue) return -1;  // a comes before b
    if (a->totalRevenue < b->totalRevenue) return +1;  // b comes before a
    // sort in increasing order of name for the same totalRevenue
    if (a->name < b->name) return -1;  // a comes before b
    if (a->name > b->name) return +1;  // b comes before a
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    ifstream statFile;
    string productName;
    double price;
    int productNumber, soldNumber;
    Selling *productArray[100];
    int numProduct = 0;

    statFile.open("sales.txt");

    while (numProduct < 100 && statFile >> productNumber >> productName >> price >> soldNumber) {
        Selling *aSelling = new Selling;
        aSelling->productNumber = productNumber;
        aSelling->name = productName;
        aSelling->price = price;
        aSelling->soldNumber = soldNumber;
        aSelling->totalRevenue = price * soldNumber;
        productArray[numProduct++] = aSelling;

        //cout << aSelling->productNumber<< " " << aSelling->name << " " 
        //     << aSelling->price << " " << aSelling->soldNumber << " " 
        //     << aSelling->totalRevenue << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numProduct; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numProduct; j++) {
            if (compareSellings(productArray[i], productArray[j]) > 0) {
                Selling *aSelling = productArray[i];
                productArray[i] = productArray[j];
                productArray[j] = aSelling;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "The top selling product is " << productArray[0]->name
         << ", with total sales of " << productArray[0]->totalRevenue << endl;
    cout << "The second selling product is " << productArray[1]->name
         << ", with total sales of " << productArray[1]->totalRevenue << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Further remarks:

- you might use a more efficient sorting method
- you should free the allocated objects
- you should use `<algorithms>` and dynamic arrays of objects instead of allocating the objects with `new` and manipulating naked pointers.
- you should handle exceptions

Comment: Ah! Slippery Finger Syndrome - understood!

Comment: @chqrlie thank you. Can you tell me where I can read more about how to use your sorting method? Or any way to practice this. I wanna understand it more.

Comment: @MinhNguyen: I did not change the sorting method: you use a variant of bubble sort / insertion sort that is simple but inefficient for large sets. Moving the comparison code to a separate function makes it more readable and easier to change. There are more efficient sorting methods such as mergesort and quicksort, look them up on wikipedia. Note also that selecting the top 2 elements can be done even more efficiently with two linear scans.